# Proper way to dynamically create content for URL where file does not exist on server

Tags: javascript, .htaccess, routes, url-routing, angularjs-routing

When I used angular, the router could catch any url that the user request and load the proper template. For example, if a user went to `mysite.com/blog` the angular router could provide the template even though there is no file called `blog` on my server.

I'm now working without angular on a web app that creates a page for every user using their username as the URL (like twitch.tv or twitter). I have found that loading `mysite.com/username` loads the `index.php` and I can grab the username out of the URL using `window.location.pathname` and then load content for that user. I'm honestly not quite sure why this is working. My .htaccess file consists of: `ErrorDocument 404 /` but if it redirects on File Not Found, why does the url remain with `/username` appended?

My method seems hack-y, and sometimes I get errors that say `/username` was not found, and also the `mysite.com/username` doesn't save as a suggestion of recently visited sites, I'm guessing because it never found the document.

Can someone explain more on how this redirecting works, and what the best practice is for this type of dynamic routing?

Answer (score 0):

`ErrorDocument` has several ways you can use it. The way you use it, with an url relative to the `DocumentRoot`, Apache will use an internal rewrite to serve the content of the page. As far as I know, Apache will serve the original http status code, which is 404 in this case.

If you want your index.php file to function as the router, you can use mod_rewrite to internally rewrite all requests to this script. The script then decides what to do. You need to enable mod_rewrite if it isn't enabled already and restart Apache.

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Alternatively, you can decide to only do this when the requested resource looks like a username:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^[^/]+$ index.php [L]
```

Or if the requested resource is not an existing directory or file. This method is likely slower than the other methods, as subrequests need to be done to check this.

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

You can find more information about mod_rewrite on it's [documentation page](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html).